# How can I delete partially downloaded macOS installer files?

Tags: mojave, software-update, disk-space

I was downloading the Mojave installer using the following command:

`sudo softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.14.6`

When the download reached about 50%, I had to cancel it by keyboard interrupt. My system storage is now reduced by 3GB, and I can't seem to find any partial downloads in `/Applications/`.

So how do I delete the partially downloaded installer to recover the lost space?

Comment: Why not resume the download so the system cleans up and drops all the data into /Applications? A reboot often will clean the partial downloads without messing, but if you are not low on disk space, I think it keeps it in case you resume later.

Answer (score 1):

`man softwareupdate` says that

> Updates are downloaded to `/Library/Updates`

Can you check and see if it's at this location?